# Maintain Product Image URL in Moqui

Tags: moqui

Our product-specific images are at CDN and we want to store the image URL.

I found that we can do it in ProductContent with image type [PcntImageUrlOriginal]. Do we have an existing service?

Comment: You mean for creating this new product content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt crud service:

`create#mantle.product.ProductContent` and set the contentLocation to a url I guess

The following is not an option as it receives the contents of the file as well as the extension but down below uses the inbuilt crud service.

```
mantle.product.ProductServices.create#ProductContent
```

declared in mantle-usl/service/mantle/product/ProductServices.xml